# Google sheets conditional formatting when one referenced cell is null and another is under a certain value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to set up conditional formatting to highlight cells where both the cell in that row in another column is blank, and the cell in question is under a certain value. In particular, we have a "Status" column and a "population" column. I want to highlight every cell in the population column where the status column in that row is blank. Here's what I have written, for some reason it's not highlighting the cells that should be highlighted!

=AND(C:C="<>",H:H<800)
I have also tried
=IF(=AND(C:C="<>",H:H<800),TRUE,FALSE) ... i've also tried reversing the false and true options, and specificing C2 and H2 rather than C:C and H:H. I'm clearly missing something here!

Answer (score 0):

In conditional formatting you have to set the formula as if it were written for the first cell in the range. Then it will "drag" automatically. Also, if you're trying to have blank cells you can say `=""`

For example:

```
=AND(C2="",H2<800)
```